# Como colocar uma cor em APENAS uma variável em C?

Tags: c

Como posso colocar uma cor em APENAS uma variável do meu código em C?

Só consegui mudar todas as cores de TODAS de todas as letras com `system("color 02");` com a biblioteca `#include <conio.h>`.

Mas como fazer para que eu tenha várias cores na mesma tela?

Por exemplo, como colocaria cada nome de cor ali com sua própria cor na mesma tela?

**Edit: mesmo que eu coloque vários system color 02 ou textcolor ele troca apenas uma vez a cor da letra e não possibilita várias cores...**

```
printf("\t\t================ MENU ==================\n");
printf("\n\t\t\tDigite 1 para a cor verde\n");
printf("\t\t\tDigite 2 para a cor azul\n");
printf("\t\t\tDigite 3 para a cor amarelo\n");
printf("\t\t\tDigite 4 para a cor vermelho\n");
printf("\t\t\tDigite 5 para a cor roxo\n");
printf("\t\t\tDigite 6 para a cor marrom\n\n");
printf("\t\t================ MENU ==================\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RED   "\x1B[31m"
#define GRN   "\x1B[32m"
#define YEL   "\x1B[33m"
#define BLU   "\x1B[34m"
#define MAG   "\x1B[35m"
#define CYN   "\x1B[36m"
#define WHT   "\x1B[37m"
#define RESET "\x1B[0m"

int main()
{
  printf(RED "red\n" RESET);
  printf(GRN "green\n" RESET);
  printf(YEL "yellow\n" RESET);
  printf(BLU "blue\n" RESET);
  printf(MAG "magenta\n" RESET);
  printf(CYN "cyan\n" RESET);
  printf(WHT "white\n" RESET);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo, compilou mas as letras ficam com caracteres estranhos em seu lugar

Comment: Isso funciona se o seu Windows for mais novo que 10 Threshold 2 (ou se for Unix, claro), senão tem que usar a API de console do Windows